# Effaceing group cohomology of restricted representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Suppose we have a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ in $G$.

Everything below in characteristic zero.

My question is simple: given a finite dimensional representation $V$ of $G$, a positive integer $n$, and a cohomology class $\alpha\in H^n(N,V|_N)$, which conditions are known to guarantee the existence of a finite dimensional representation $W$ containing $V$ such that the induced morphism $H^n(N,V|_N)\to H^n(N,W|_N)$ kills $\alpha$?

An argument due to Beilinson shows that this is possible when $N$ is a free group, but I don't know any other cases.

Comment: What's a reference for Beilinson's result?

Comment: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/teaching/mat731f15/Beilinson.pdf, proof of lemma 2.1.2